# Evaluating the src attribute in a HTML image tag

Tags: jquery, html, latex

I'm going in circles on this one and am hoping you can help.

In my HTML file I have an image tag generated by a third-party plugin that looks like this:

```
<p><img alt="{x_{3}}^{4}" src="http://latex.abcd.com/gif.latex?%5Cdpi%7B100%7D%20%5Cfn_phv%20%7Bx_%7B3%7D%7D%5E%7B4%7D" /></p>
```

I would like to be able to do away with the reference to abcd.com and instead have the src point to the data itself. Something like...

```
<p><img alt="{x_{3}}^{4}" src="data:image/png;base64, ..." /></p>
```

How would I go about this in jquery?

Thanks!

Mmiz

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/4613398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this example will help you http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/yvq5y/

but in your case instead of:

`var imageUrl = $(this).find('[name=url]').val();`

add the following line

`var imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');`

something like that should do it for you.

PS: I don't own the fiddle I just found it online

**UPDATE**

Here's a version with a fix for the CORS problem

https://jsfiddle.net/9hjpdect/9/

Comment: I ran into the following error : "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ". So I suspect I can't use this approach, right?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/9hjpdect/9/ and don't forget to start the link with https @user1072910